# Dimension of Zariski closure of an infinite discrete group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, zariski-topology

Let $ \Gamma $ be a subgroup of $ G:=GL(n,\mathbb{C}) $ which is discrete with respect to the manifold topology on $ G $. Let $ \overline{\Gamma} $ be the Zariski closure of $ \Gamma $. Suppose that $ \Gamma $ is infinite. Can we conclude that $ \overline{\Gamma} $ is a positive dimensional Lie group?

Moreover, is there any way to determine the dimension of the manifold $ \overline{\Gamma} $ based on information about $ \Gamma $? For example is $ dim( \overline{\Gamma}) $ always greater than the free rank of the abelianization of $ \Gamma $?

It seems that [What do the closures of cyclic groups in $\textrm{GL}_n$ look like?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1717692/what-do-the-closures-of-cyclic-groups-in-textrmgl-n-look-like)
already shows that the above conjecture about free rank is false. Maybe $ dim( \overline{\Gamma}) $ is bounded above by $ n $ times the free rank of the abelianization of $ \Gamma $?

Comment: This has nothing to do with groups, just some basic AG: Zero dimensional implies finite.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I'm confused if $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z}\subseteq \mathbb{G}_a=G$ then this is discrete for the manifold topology, but its closure is $G$ itself.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: Yes, this is all true, why confusion? OP is asking if the Zariski closure of an infinite subset of an affine space (over ${\mathbb C}$) can be zero-dimensional (for some undefined notion of dimension, but presumably either in the sense of Lebesgue covering dimension for the classical topology or in AG sense). The answer is clear in both settings, I do not see any confusion.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Ah, I misunderstood your comment to mean "and therefore $\overline{\Gamma}$ must be finite" and I was quite confused. I understand now you meant it the opposite: if the closure of $\Gamma$ is zero-dimensiona, thne it is finite, and so the same is true of $\Gamma$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I would like to add one more small thing though. While I agree 100% with what you said mathematically, I think it's worth emphasizing that it has less to do with the fact that zero-dimensional implies finite, and more that zero-dimensional implies discrete. But, unlike $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ with the usual topology, $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ with the Zariski topology is quasi-compcat (and in fact Noetherian) and so now we actually see discrete implies finite.